# Programming a BFS - Shortest Path - in Python

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I'm new to Python and am trying to write a BFS to return a shortest path of a graph. The length of each edge is 6.

Note: This is a problem on HackerRank.

My code works for 3 out of 6 of the testcases, but fails the other 3. I have no idea why and can't really debug as the testcases are too big.

My code is :

```
# Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT    

def shortestPath():
    testCases = int(raw_input())

    for a in range(testCases):
        nodes,edges = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
        numNodes,edges = [int(nodes), int(edges)]

        edgeList = []

        # input data
        for b in range(edges):
            a,b = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
            a,b = [int(a), int(b)]
            edgeList += [[a,b]]
        root = int(raw_input())

        marked = [] # what I've checked
        fringe = [root] # things to check
        distances = {} # what to return
        levels = {root: 0} # the level of each element
        counter = 1

        # do the BFS
        while fringe != []:
            node = fringe[0]
            fringe.remove(node)
            marked += [node]
            if counter > levels[node] + 1:
                counter = levels[node] + 1
            nbrsList = Nbrs(node, edgeList)
            for v in nbrsList:
                levels[v] = counter
                if v not in fringe and v not in marked:
                    distances[v] = 6*counter
                    fringe += [v]
            counter += 1

        listOfNodes = nodeList(edgeList, numNodes)

        for node in listOfNodes:
            if node != root:
                if node in distances:
                    print distances[node],
                else:
                    print -1,  
        print ""
    print ""

def nodeList(edges, numNodes):
    nodes = []
    for edge in edges:
        for element in edge:
            if element not in nodes:
                nodes += [element]
    nodes.sort()

    for x in range(1,numNodes+1):
        if x not in nodes:
            nodes += [x]
    nodes.sort()
    return nodes


def Nbrs(node, edges):
    tempList = []
    for edge in edges:
        if node in edge:
            for element in edge:
                if element != node:
                    tempList += [element]
    return tempList
```

For example, I used the test case of:

> 1
>   5 8
>   1 2
>   3 4
>   4 5
>   5 2
>   2 4
>   2 3
>   1 3
>   1 4
>   3

where the first line is the number of testcases, the second line is number of nodes, number of edges, the remaining n-1 lines are edges, and the last line is the root.

This works perfectly well. I try and change it to everything I can think of and it seems to work. Yet with the site's testcase of 70 nodes and 1988 edges, my answer is too high for many of the nodes.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: how exactly does it fail? syntax, runtime, time limit exceeded?

Comment: Why do the size of the test cases prevent debugging?

Comment: How can we know what's wrong without seeing the test cases?

Comment: The answer I get is wrong. There must be a logic error somewhere, but I can't figure out where it is. I've tried creating smaller graphs with cycles, a root that accesses every node, but all of those seem to work fine.

Comment: Very few people are going to read through all your question and all your code. If you want to increase your chances of getting an answer, I suggest you add a simple example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: The problem is that the test case that fails is huge. It has 70 nodes and 1988 edges and is correct for many of the nodes, but incorrect for others and I have no idea what the problem is. Sorry for the ambiguity, but I'm not quite sure how to phrase the problem, when I'm not even sure what the problem is myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: the original 'problem' condition I identified was wrong, corrected now**

There's a problem with how you set `counter` and `levels`.

Assuming `R` is the root node, `A`, `B` and `C` are other nodes, your code is currently having an issue when

```
R <-> A
A <-> B
R <-> B
B <-> C
```

And the relationships are evaluated in that order.  It thinks the shortest path from R to C is R -> A -> B -> C rather than R -> B -> C.

You can reproduce the issue by reordering your example input set:

> 1
>   5 8
>   1 2
>   1 3  # Moved this and
>   1 4  # this up
>   3 4
>   4 5
>   5 2
>   2 4
>   2 3
>   3

This changes your output such that the distance of the `5` node becomes 18 not 12.

I *think* the solution is to just put the `levels[v] = counter` inside the conditional block, i.e.

```
for v in nbrsList:
    if v not in fringe and v not in marked:
        levels[v] = counter
        distances[v] = 6*counter
        fringe += [v]
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much.